# error on loading Sql value to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that it sounds wrong. Is It possible to get the SQL value on the dropdown list anyway, so that one of the ListItem in dropdownlist is similar to SQL.

here is my code:

```
private void ReviewButtonPinsDetails()
{
      con.Open();
      cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT quo_ProdCategory,quo_ProdType
                              ,quo_JobDesc,quo_PrintProcess
                              ,quo_File,quo_Finishing
                              ,quo_Quantity
                              FROM JobQuotations1
                              WHERE TransactionID = @id
                              AND TransactionNum = @Num", con);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text);

       rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       if (rdr.HasRows)
       {
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
              ddlProducts.Text = rdr["quo_ProductCategory"].ToString();
              ddlProdName.Text = rdr["quo_ProdType"].ToString();
              txtJobDesc.Text = rdr["quo_JobDesc"].ToString();
              ddlPrintProc.Text = rdr["quo_PrintProcess"].ToString();
              lblFileName.Text = rdr["quo_File"].ToString();
              txtFinishing.Text = rdr["quo_Finishing"].ToString();
              txtQty.Text = rdr["quo_Quantity"].ToString();
          }
      }
      con.Close();
      lblFileStatus.Text = "Previous File";
}
```

When the customer wanted to review His/Her order and select the row on grid view It suppose to restore the value of The textboxes and dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the framework that you are working in but have you considered using the functionality offered by the INotifyPropertyChangedinterface.

Which will allow you to use the PropertyChangedEventHandler object.

Bind the textbox in the view to a property in your model.

You could then create some properties in the class that will hold the data for the text boxes and dropdowns and ensure that when a new property is set the 
PropertyChangedEventHandler object you have created will handle updating the property in the view.

Answer (score 0):

First bind your dropdownlist before Sql Value assign to it.

For example:

```
bindProducts(ddlProducts);
ddlProducts.SelectedValue = rdr["quo_ProductCategory"].ToString();
```

**bindProducts(ddl as DropDownList)** is the method for bind the product list to dropdownlist.

Comment: should I call the bindProduct inside my class?

Comment: I gave a example of bind a dropdown. You can bind it on your own way but before assigning, dropdown should have value.